# Show that a collection of finite unions of sets of the form $(a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is an algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

The following is a question from Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and their Applications*.

**(Question 23 page 32)**

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of finite unions of sets of the form $(a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ where $- \infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra on $\mathbb{Q}$.

The hint given in the question is to first show that the set $\mathcal{E}$ of all intervals of the form $(a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ where $- \infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$ form an elementary family, and then to use a theorem in the text that says the collection of finite disjoint members of an elementary family is an algebra.

However to show that $\mathcal{E}$ is an elementary family I need to show that it contains the empty set, which I haven't been able to do. I feel like there is some convention I am not aware of that allows us to say that $\mathcal{E}$ contains the empty set.

Is anyone aware of such a convention? If not how can I show that $\mathcal{E}$ contains the empty set?

Comment: "Finite union" means (here) the union of $0$ or more. The union of no sets at all is $\emptyset$.